# SELECT DISTINCT not working

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Why does this query produce an "Duplicate entry" error?

```
TRUNCATE parim_firm_tag_names;
INSERT INTO parim_firm_tag_names (firm_tag_name_value) 
    SELECT DISTINCT sona 
    FROM parim_marksona;
```

Error message:

> SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry '1-??????? ??????' for key
>   'firm_tag_name_value'

As you can see, `firm_tag_name_value` has an unique index, I use `DISTINCT` select and I'm truncating all existing data from `tag_names`.

What could produce this error?

Comment: What are the definitions of both tables? Maybe an affect of implicit conversions between differing datatypes or different case sensitivity options?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with character sets (collations) in `parim_marksona.sona` vs `parim_firm_tag_names.firm_tag_name_value`. The question-marks in the error message suggest there are some non-English characters in the data.

Comment: Please provide the table structure to see the exact reason for this error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This could be happening because of different `collations` defined on both tables `parim_firm_tag_names` and  `parim_marksona` as string comparisons using distinct may results in different values on case sensitive and case insensitive `collation` values.

You can check `collation` of columns using this query:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM parim_marksona;
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM parim_firm_tag_names;
```

To avoid this error, you can convert collation of column `sona` to the collation of column `firm_tag_name_value` using `COLLATE`, while selecting the distinct values from table `parim_marksona`.

Assuming collation of column `firm_tag_name_value` as `latin1_swedish_cs`:

```
TRUNCATE parim_firm_tag_names;

INSERT INTO parim_firm_tag_names (firm_tag_name_value)
    SELECT DISTINCT sona COLLATE latin1_swedish_cs
    FROM parim_marksona;
```

This should work without errors.

For more details refer manual [Column Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html).

Comment: Yeah, just figured that out :) You are winner :)

Answer (score 1):

Different character sets between the two tables, perhaps?